# How to get users from Keycloak REST API - Keycloak API response 403

Tags: keycloak

Hi I'm trying to use the Keycloak API but I don't understand very well how it works. I want to obtain all the users of a realm. So I first obtain a token using this endpoint: `/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token` with this params in the request body:

- client_id
- grant_type
- username
- password
- client_secret

The first question is: What client should I use?

Then I call this endpoint: `/admin/realms/master/users` with the token in the Authorization header, but I get a 403 status code and I don't understand why.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally: 403 = you don't have permissions to perform requested action (to view users in this particular case). You need to define `Client Roles` (`realm-management`) for used user/client and assign right role (`view-users` role in this case):

Keycloak 17+ UI:
[image]

Or Keycloak 17+ UI - client with `Service Accounts Enabled` enabled:
[image]

Keycloak 17- UI:
[image]

Comment: Could you please have a look at my Keycloak-related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70376766/2886891 ? Thanks.

Comment: Menu has changed over the years. Nowadays (Keycloak 17.0) client admin-cli has a menu item "Service Account Roles".

Comment: where is it now?

Comment: somewhy i can read users with 'admin-cli' client but can't with others. And can't find what the difference

Answer (score 22):

You need two steps

- first get an access token from the admin-cli client of the master realm
- second call the admin rest api with the access token, set Bearer as prefix in the 
  Authorization header.

```
# get an access token
curl -X POST \
  https://<HOST>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'grant_type=password&username=<USERNAME>l&password=<PASSWORD>&client_id=admin-cli'

# get all users of gateway realm, use the token from above and use Bearer as prefix
curl -X GET \
  https://<HOST>/auth/admin/realms/gateway/users \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkI...' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Comment: slight correction, With keycloak 19+, /auth  from the URI needs to be removed.

Comment: I am getting this error ```{"error":"unknown_error"}%```