# Is there any part of JWT Keycloak token which can be used as a unique ID of the token itself?

Tags: security, jwt, keycloak, access-token

##### Edit

My question was originally before about Keycloak token only, but the solution I found is applicable for JWT in general, regardless of Keycloak.

##### Background / Motivation

Based on the JWT Keycloak token, I fetch some additional information of the user (the `sub` field) from my database. I'd like to cache the information and I am looking for an appropriate key to the cache.

I do not want to use the `sub` field because I want the cache entry to invalidate when the Keycloak token changes (= when a new token is generated for the same user).

I can easily use the whole Keycloak token or its third part (the signature) as the key. However, it is quite a long string.

##### Question

Is there any *field* in the JWT Keycloak token, which may be used as a unique ID of this particular token? Which is guaranteed to be always present, and always change for a new instance of the token.

Does the `sid` field work like this? At least it seems to be different from `sub`.

There are several UUIDs in the Keycloak token and I am confused by the documentation. I found only this [clearly arranged table](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_action_token_anatomy) explaining the meaning of the Keycloak token fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the detailed documentation of JWT: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519

The field is *not* keycloak specific, it is defined in the JWT standard.

There is specified the [field `jti`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) as:

> The **`jti` (JWT ID)** claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT. The identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that there is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally assigned to a different data object; if the application uses multiple issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values produced by different issuers as well.  **The `jti` claim can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed.**  The `jti` value is a case-sensitive string.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

The field exactly matches my requirement to "provide a unique ID of this particular token". And it seems that our keycloak server assigns the field a UUID.

The documentation even suggests using the field as a cache key by saying that

> the `jti` claim can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed,

which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use case, two fields I can think of using is `id / email id` and expiration.

1. Id / email id is unique and always present, so that serves your purpose.
2. Expiration alone cannot be used as 2 tokens generated for 2 users at same time may have same expiration. Then why am I asking to use? If your cache does not support TTL, then there might be stale entries unnecessarily occupying your cache. So if you keep your key as "expiration.id", then you can maybe run a side job every 24 hours or so to delete stale entries from cache , based on first part i.e. expiration.

Here is sample Keycloak token object in my Java app:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I might be wrong but that id does not belong to the token it self but rather to the Java object wrapping the token.

Comment: And what exactly is `sid`? Couldn't this field work as the "unique ID of the Keycloak token"?

Comment: @dreamcrash your guess might be correct. I don't have a setup with me to validate that. This pic is from my another answer.

Comment: @HonzaZidek I am not aware about `sid`. It doesn't seem part of the token in above data I have. I don't have setup to check the latest token structure. There can be a dozen different approaches. I suggested 1. :)

Comment: If what @dreamcrash is guessing is correct, then you may use some other param like `email id` instead of `id`, which will be unique to the user.

Comment: @tryingToLearn As the user ID I am using **`sub`** (subject, see https://jwt.io/introduction): "**Registered claims**: These are a set of predefined claims which are not mandatory but recommended, to provide a set of useful, interoperable claims. Some of them are: `iss` (issuer), `exp` (expiration time), `sub` (subject), `aud` (audience), and others." https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_action_token_anatomy confirms this for Keycloak token.