# 403 Forbidden Error in Keycloak API (view-users)

Tags: c#, permissions, keycloak, roles

I'm having issues trying to access auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users API. I've already tried everything from other questions and answers, but nothing seems to work. Steps that I did:

1. The user already has a role that has `realm-management` and `view-users` on it.
2. I've already assigned this same `role` to my client in the scopes section.
3. I can't have `Service Accounts Enabled` in my client because I need to have `Access Type` as `confidential`, and that won't allow my user to access Login page from Application.
4. I've also already tried to give 'view-users' role to my user and to my client individually as a `Client role`, it also didn't work.

My code in C#:

```
var authState = await AuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = authState.user;
var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();

_accessToken = _tokenResult.Value;

_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm name}/users");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

// Rest of code that gets response and deserializes to array of users.
```

I honestly don't know what to do. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get users from Keycloak REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535440/how-to-get-users-from-keycloak-rest-api)

Comment: @JanGaraj no, my friend. As mentioned, I've already tried other answers and they don't seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since Keycloak's Rest API endpoints changes very often (e.g. BasePath, Signature etc.), I found very useful:

1. login to keycloak's admin panel (UI) and see from developer tools the endpoint for fetching the users (on `Users` menu item in `Manage` group parent). In particular, `{$HOST}/admin/realms/{$REALM_NAME}/users` is the endpoint in version `17.0.1`.
2. I also assigned the client role `view-users` from `realm-management` to one of my realm users as it is displayed below (UI of version `17.0.1`)
   [image]
3. I was able to fetch the users by just adding user's access token to the request.